# nls line of best fit - how to force plotting of line?

Tags: r, error-handling, nls

I am trying to write a basic function to add some lines of best fit to plots using `nls`.
This works fine unless the data just happens to be defined exactly by the formula passed to `nls`. I'm aware of the issues and that this is documented behaviour [as reported here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13053/singular-gradient-error-in-nls-with-correct-starting-values).

My question though is how can I get around this and force a line of best fit to be plotted regardless of the data exactly being described by the model? Is there a way to detect the data matches exactly and plot the perfectly fitting curve? My current dodgy solution is:

```
#test data
x <- 1:10
y <- x^2
plot(x, y, pch=20)

# polynomial line of best fit
f <- function(x,a,b,d) {(a*x^2) + (b*x) + d}
fit <- nls(y ~ f(x,a,b,d), start = c(a=1, b=1, d=1)) 
co <- coef(fit)
curve(f(x, a=co[1], b=co[2], d=co[3]), add = TRUE, col="red", lwd=2)
```

Which fails with the error:

```
Error in nls(y ~ f(x, a, b, d), start = c(a = 1, b = 1, d = 1)) : 
  singular gradient
```

The easy fix I apply is to `jitter` the data slightly, but this seems a bit destructive and hackish.

```
# the above code works after doing...
y <- jitter(x^2)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: All the same, in the real world, this situation will never happen.  There's always measurement error.  Unless you're a teacher who's giving an R exam and devilishly supplying your students with perfect datasets, that is :-) .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I've had this kind of problems with data exported from Excel as CSV (and thereby rounded to visible digits) if n was small.

Comment: @Roland, I suppose if you round your test data inappropriately (i.e. losing valid sig figs), you get what you deserve :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Well, if you do rounding appropriate for measurement precision and then do regression with n=4 (which shouldn't be done, but such is life) ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Use Levenberg-Marquardt](http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-better-nls/).

```
x <- 1:10
y <- x^2

f <- function(x,a,b,d) {(a*x^2) + (b*x) + d}
fit <- nls(y ~ f(x,a,b,d), start = c(a=1, b=0, d=0)) 

Error in nls(y ~ f(x, a, b, d), start = c(a = 1, b = 0, d = 0)) : 
  number of iterations exceeded maximum of 50

library(minpack.lm)
fit <- nlsLM(y ~ f(x,a,b,d), start = c(a=1, b=0, d=0))
summary(fit)

Formula: y ~ f(x, a, b, d)

Parameters:
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
a        1          0     Inf   <2e-16 ***
b        0          0      NA       NA    
d        0          0      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0 on 7 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.49e-08
```

Note that I had to adjust the starting values and the result is sensitive to starting values.

```
fit <- nlsLM(y ~ f(x,a,b,d), start = c(a=1, b=0.1, d=0.1))

Parameters:
    Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
a  1.000e+00  2.083e-09  4.800e+08  < 2e-16 ***
b -7.693e-08  1.491e-08 -5.160e+00  0.00131 ** 
d  1.450e-07  1.412e-08  1.027e+01  1.8e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 6.191e-08 on 7 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 3 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.49e-08
```